# the separators are not working properly in regular expression split method

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
text = 'The quick. black n brown? fox jumps*over the lazy dog.'
print(re.split('; |, |\? |. ',text))
```

This is giving me an output of:

```
['Th', 'quick', 'brown', 'fo', 'jumps*ove', 'th', 'laz', 'dog.']
```

but I want that string to be split as

```
['The quick.', 'black n brown?', 'fox jumps*over the lazy dog.']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage a zero-width positive lookbehind here:

```
re.split('(?<=[;,.?]) ',text)
```

- `(?<=[;,.?])` is zero-width positive lookbehind that matches any of `;`, `,`, `.`, `?` literally; this is followed by a space to be matched

**Example:**

```
In [1461]: text = 'The quick. black n brown? fox jumps*over the lazy dog.'                                                                                                                                  

In [1462]: re.split(r'(?<=[;,.?]) ',text)                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[1462]: ['The quick.', 'black n brown?', 'fox jumps*over the lazy dog.']
```

---

In your try, if you replace `.` (any character) with a escaped version to get litaral `.` i.e. `\.` you would get *closer to the desired output*:

```
In [1463]: text = 'The quick. black n brown? fox jumps*over the lazy dog.'                                                                                                                                  

In [1464]: re.split(r'; |, |\? |. ',text)                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[1464]: ['Th', 'quick', 'blac', '', 'brown', 'fo', 'jumps*ove', 'th', 'laz', 'dog.']

In [1465]: re.split(r'; |, |\? |\. ',text)                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[1465]: ['The quick', 'black n brown', 'fox jumps*over the lazy dog.']
```

As all the patterns have single characters followed by a space, you can make the pattern more compact by using character class:

```
In [1466]: re.split(r'[;,?.] ',text)                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[1466]: ['The quick', 'black n brown', 'fox jumps*over the lazy dog.']
```

You don't need to escape Regex tokens inside character class `[]`.

Also, make Regex patterns raw by enclosing the pattern string with `r`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you needed, your regex should have the dot escaped:

```
print(re.split('; |, |\? |\. ',text)
```

Comment: Not quite there. It does not generate the output OP wants, which is `['The quick.', 'black n brown?', 'fox jumps*over the lazy dog.']` but it solves one issue.